# Which of these Paths should I use as the value of JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, oracle, paths

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I have downloaded JDK 7.0 from Oracle website and untar'ed and put it in a folder `/opt/JDK/`, such that the final install directory is **`/opt/JDK/jdk1.7.0_80`** Then I executed the following commands given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541853/oracle-java-7-installation-in-ubuntu-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-er/22955890#22955890):

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac
update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

I want to set the **`JAVA_HOME`** environment variable. I know how to do it using `/etc/environment`. The confusion is which path to use.

Should I use **`/usr/bin/java`**?

Or should I use **`/opt/JDK/jdk1.7.0_80`**?

Or should I use **`/opt/JDK/jdk1.7.0_80/bin`**?

The output of `update-alternatives --config java` is:

```
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/JDK/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java   1         auto mode
* 1            /opt/JDK/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see two alternatives are identical, so you can use both of them. Simply you can use following command to set `JAVA_HOME`:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

The command `update-alternatives --config java` is used when you have different JAVA installed on your machine. For example Mine is as follow:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
```

---

```
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
```